# How could I implement a streaming Web Application in apache/php/sf1.4/jquery/flash/html 5?

Tags: php, flash, html, stream, webcam

I want to implement a one-to-one webcam conversation (like a skype call) between two users of my web application. For the client side I found this very nice jQuery plugin with Flash libraries, but I don't know how the rest of the process should work.. upload the video to the server (optionally save it) stream the video. and the other user to receive it.

Could you suggest any script or any workflow on how this system should be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot rely on upload/download video approach. You need a realtime communication. You could rely on Flash technology (client) using an AMF Server on server side.

You could check this OpenMeeting open source project
[http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/](http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings)

Comment: OpenMeetings indeed started migration to HTML5 using Apache Wicket.